# Trying to propagate Result for file open(std::fs::File)

Tags: rust

I've written what I thought was a pretty simple function (ignoring `build_file_path` implementation):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::io::{self, Read};

pub enum FileType {
    XhtmlFile,
    TxtFile,
}

fn create_file(file_type: FileType, file_name: String) -> Result<File, io::Error> {
     let mut file_path: String = file_name.to_owned();

    let file_type_ending = match file_type {
        FileType::XhtmlFile => ".xhtml",
        FileType::TxtFile =>  ".txt",
    };
    file_path.push_str(&file_type_ending);
    let path = Path::new(&file_path);
    
    // Open a file in write-only mode, returns io::Result<File>
    return File::create(&path)?;
}
```

But I get an error when I try to compile it:

```
error[E0308]: `?` operator has incompatible types
  --> src\document_writer.rs:87:12
   |
87 |     return File::create(&path)?;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Result<File, Error>`, found `File`
   |
   = note: `?` operator cannot convert from `File` to `Result<File, std::io::Error>`
   = note: expected enum `Result<File, std::io::Error>`
```

I want to propagate the error up to handle it elsewhere, and just reading through the examples [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html), this seemed like the way to do it. I must be missing something important.

As FYI, the reason I've included an explicit return statement is that otherwise I also get a compile error about having no return (which also seems different from the examples, but I don't mind explicitly returning

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You forgot to `Ok`-wrap the result. (Alternatively, you unnecessarily unwrapped the `Result` of `File::create`.)

Comment: I added the path definition function. I assume that's why my question got downvoted. It just seemed irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implicitly return you need to omit the semicolon. As for the return type. `File::create(&path)` returns a result and you are unwrapping it with `?` causing the return type to be `File` instead of `Result<File, io::Error>`

```
let foo: File = File::create(&path)?;
let bar: Result<File, io::Error> = File::create(&path);
```

```
fn create_file(file_type: FileType, file_name: String) -> Result<File, io::Error> {
    let path: &Path = &build_file_path(file_name, file_type);

    let display = path.display();

    // Open a file in write-only mode, returns io::Result<File>
    File::create(&path)
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice the missing semicolon in the last expression. That's very clever!